# How do i find the 40th byte from a binary file using Scheme language?

Tags: scheme, byte

Hi I am trying to find the the 40th byte from a binary file using scheme commands.

```
(define FileName "D:/work_dsi/Stories/WriterOptions/Tests/block_english.model")

(define fPtr (open-input-file FileName))

(define sRec "1")

(((sRec (read-byte fPtr)))

    do
     ((eof-object? sRec ))
    (print sRec)
    (define sRec (read-byte fPtr))
)
(close-input-port fPtr)
```

i tried with this expression for a better understanding of the concept , but couldn't achieve anything.

Comment: It looks like you need to study the most fundamental basics of Scheme a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You need these functions:

- [with-input-from-file](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html?q=with-input#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._with-input-from-file%29%29): allows you to read from given file (file is set as [current-input-port](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html?q=with-input#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._current-input-port%29%29))
- [port->bytes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._port-%7E3ebytes%29%29): you get all bytes from given port or current input port, result is *byte string*
- [bytes-ref](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/bytestrings.html?q=byte-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._bytes-ref%29%29): get nth byte from *byte string*

```
(require racket/port)

(with-input-from-file
    "D:/work_dsi/Stories/WriterOptions/Tests/block_english.model"
  (lambda ()
    (bytes-ref (port->bytes) 39)))
```

This function will return number. For reading text files, you can convert that number with [integer->char](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html?q=bytes-%3Echar#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._integer-%7E3echar%29%29) to get character.

Comment: May i know what this is for ? (string->path "C:\\Users\\mapud\\Documents\\bytefile.txt") cause i already have defined a binary file for the function.

Comment: @UmeshV Actually, you don't need that- check edited version.

Answer (score 0):

A version using only standard R7RS functions (In particular, `open-binary-input-file` and `read-u8` from the `file` library:

```lisp
(import (scheme file))
(define (read-nth-byte filename n)
  (call-with-port
   (open-binary-input-file filename)
   (lambda (inp)
     (do ((i 1 (+ i 1))
          (byte (read-u8 inp) (read-u8 inp)))
         ((= i n) byte)
       (if (eof-object? byte) (error "Premature end of file"))))))
```

To avoid reading a large chunk of the file into memory for large values of `n`, this one reads and discards bytes until it hits the `n`th byte. (It would be nice if there was a `seek` function in the standard...)

Comment: If i replace the n with 40 in the above script i am getting this output ! Error lambda: wrong argument type integer (expected symbol)

Comment: Also for the first line command : Error top-level: unbound variable: import

Comment: @UmeshV Er... are you replacing the variable in the argument list with a literal number? Um. It's a function; just call it with the appropriate arguments. This code requires a R7RS-compliant scheme. If you're using one that doesn't support that standard, it might not work  (For example, if using chicken, you'd need to install the r7rs egg first).

Comment: hi shawn instead of reading a byte , what i have done is imported the binary file and read the characters. But i had one issue in that i was not able to get the result for this script with a string match. Kindly check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650490/i-am-trying-to-match-a-string-x-from-the-result-that-i-got-from-this-scheme .