# I am trying to match a string "#\x" from the result that i got from this scheme script, but i am always getting the final output as FALSE

Tags: scheme

I checked the output and it has the character what am searching for .

```
(define fPtr (open-input-file "block_english.model"))
(define sRec "")
(define sRec_str "")
(do
    ((sRec (read-char fPtr)))
    ((eof-object? sRec ))
    (set! sRec (read-char fPtr))
    (set! sRec_str (format #f "~s" sRec))
    (test:equal #t (substring? "#\x" sRec) "Character not found")
)
(close-input-port fPtr)
```

Comment: `"#\x"` is a syntax error, so I'm not convinced that your code outputs anything at all. Please post a [mcve]. (And as far as I can see, there is nothing that could output FALSE in that code.)

Comment: Characters are not strings. Eg. the only letter in the string `"x"` is `#\x`.

Comment: The Code in the first line was missing !! updated now.

Comment: Why read one character, print it to a one-character string, and then check if it's the substring of a different one-character string, and is the file really expected to only contain the character you look for?